# Games services login not working

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was initially using the googleApiClient builder to handle login etc but now I changed my code entirely to use the BaseGameUtils library but now all of a sudden, it won't log in.

I get an error that just says **Unknown issue with google play services** every time my main activity starts.

It also says **SignInFailureReason INTERNAL ERROR (8)**

Here is the activity:

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

    private Button playButton, leaderboardButton, rateButton, howtoButton;
    private Context appContext;

    protected static GameHelper mHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_layout);

        mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
        //leaderboard and rate listeners dependent on signed in or not
        GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                leaderboardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_highest_score)));
                    }

                });
                rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        launchMarket();
                    }

                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onSignInFailed() {
                leaderboardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Please sign-in to view the leaderboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
                rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Please sign-in to rate tri-morph", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
                System.out.println(mHelper.getSignInError().toString());
            }

        };
        mHelper.setup(listener);

        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        findViews();
        attachListeners();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void findViews() {
        playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        leaderboardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_button);
        rateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate_button);
        howtoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.howtoplay_button);
    }

    private void attachListeners() {
        // play and tutorial enabled regardless of signed in or not
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(appContext, InGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
        howtoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(appContext, TutorialActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        }
    }

    private void launchMarket() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
        Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find market app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: **I FOUND THE PROBLEM**. Apparently my application needs to have the **Drive** api enabled i nthe **Google Api Console**. I did it and it works. Now the problem is, my app doesn't have anything to do with drive. I get the feeling that the gameHelper is doing this, can I remove it somehow?

Comment: I think the Drive API needs to be enabled because you use `CLIENT_ALL`, which includes cloud saves - and as far as I understand, it is using Drive for storing the data. Not 100% sure of this though, but if you are not using cloud saves you can try using only `CLIENT_GAMES | CLIENT_PLUS` instead of `CLIENT_ALL`.

Comment: @free3dom Thanks for the comment, you should delete it and make it an answer so I can accept.

Comment: I would add it as an answer but I am not 100% sure about the accuracy of my comment - I think I read that somewhere, but can't find the source now. If you can verify that changing the `CLIENT_ALL` removes the dependency on the Drive API then I will add it as an answer, but otherwise it may be best to just leave it as a comment.

Comment: @free3dom It didn't work. I'll just leave the drive api there then, it's not hurting anyone :)

Comment: That sounds like a good solution ;) Drive might be more closely tied to the Play Games service than I thought - I just don't remember having had to explicitly enable it, but that doesn't mean I didn't.

Comment: I spend so much time with this problem, thanks a lot